# "This file is managed by Puppet. Resistance is futile." -php.ini

Tags: php, security

I opened up my php.ini file this morning because it seemed to be in a new location in my file manager for Bluehost. I honestly don't remember ever seeing it before but it is there now under my public_html folder. I opened the file and the top line reads:

"This file is managed by Puppet. Resistance is futile."

Is this something to be concerned about?

I contacted bluehost and they said it had nothing to do with them and that the top line of that file could have been added by a plugin. I haven't added any new plugins in a long time. Bluehost gave me no more information.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: You might be better off asking over at security.stackexchange.com, but [Puppet](http://www.example42.com) is a system configuration tool/suite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has to do with Bluehost, even though their customer service is denying it. [Puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)) is a *system configuration management tool*, commonly used for cloud hosting (it allows you to install apps automatically from the user panel, for instance).

Did you change your PHP configuration recently so the file got recreated, maybe?

Comment: Yes, I changed the configuration a few weeks ago, so maybe I just haven't noticed it until now. This is just the first time I noticed it and decided to open it. Seems to be an intimidating first line...

Comment: I agree about the first line. It appears that some programmer / Star Trek aficionado thought they were being funny by making a reference to the Borg.

Comment: Also - if you moved your site from another host, it could be from the other host, and BlueHost could be telling the truth.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this hasn't anything to do with Bluehost. One of my client's servers were hacked and was filled with file hackers, backdoors, etc...

The full system was scanned using ClamAV, and we removed/edited the infected files.

I then installed WordFence (since this was a Wordpress installation), and weirdly WordFence couldn't finish a scan. It however detected a php.ini file in the wp-admin directory.

Tried scanning a couple a'times, and finally removed the "innocent" php.ini, and tried again. Voila. The scan moves through perfectly.

This particular account hosted multiple domains and sub domains, so there were quite a few Wordpress installations. This php.ini file was inside of one of the Wordpress installations on an Addon domain name.

How I came across your question is when I found a php.ini file in the main domain's directory of this server I was cleaning up, and found that intimidating piece of text. Googled it, and here I am.

On a sidenote, my gut feeling tells me that your server's probably hit by malware. Ask your host to a full scan and I hope I'm wrong. To be on the safe side, don't forget to do a file consistency scan as well.